# What would be the future version of reminisce?

Tags: single-word-requests

The word reminisce is used for the past, so what would be the 'future' version of the word.

E.g.,

> You *reminisce* about the past. You _______ about the future.

Comment: *Preminisce*? How would you use the word? "We were *preminiscing* of things to come" or "Some day people will *reminisce* of things that have not yet happened" ?

Comment: Probably 'dream'.  Please give a sample sentence to show how you would use the word. You can leave a blank where it would go. At the moment there is not enough context. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe "fantasize" or "speculate".

Comment: Or 'anticipate'?

Answer (score 3):

How about **envision**?

**envision**:

to think of (something that you believe might exist or happen in the future) : to picture (something) in your mind`([Merriam-Webster Dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/envision))

Also, to imagine what a situation will be like in the future, especially a situation you intend to work toward ([Oxford Learner"s Dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/envision))

*They envision an equal society, free of poverty and disease.*

*The two men bonded over their love for envisioning the future and reminiscing about the past.* ([BooksTellYouWhy.com - An Ideal "Imagineer"](http://blog.bookstellyouwhy.com/the-many-hats-of-science-fiction-author-ray-bradbury))

Comment: +1: A decent alternative too. It also lacks the implied pleasurable aspect (at work I can envision things that I know I'll never want to reminisce about afterwards), but it's still a valid option.

Answer (score 2):

**Prescience** (noun) or **anticipate** (verb)

> Definition: knowledge of things before they exist or happen; human anticipation of the course of events; foreknowledge; foresight.

or **Premonition** or **have a premonition** (verb)

> Definition:  anticipation of an event without conscious reason

Comment: I wouldn't wholly disagree with these answers, but my only concern with them is that they both lack the pleasurable / enjoyable aspect that's usually associated with reminiscing. You can anticipate or have a premonition about unpleasant events as well as pleasurable ones.

Comment: In short, when you're thinking about desirable future events and looking forward to them happening, you're anticipating them. Nobody would say they're anticipating their root canal, unless they really like root canals.

Comment: I actually posted anticipate as an answer before I realized Graffito had already posted the same word. It's the best word I can think of for this case.

Answer (score 1):

Reminiscing, by definition, involves recalling past events. Given the nature of time's arrow and light cones (though that's one for the Physics group) you can't have an equivalent of reminiscing about ***future*** events because there is no way of knowing what those events will be.

Though if anyone cares to pass on next week's Powerball numbers I'll be most grateful.

What you can of course do is either [daydream](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/daydream) about the future:

> A series of pleasant thoughts that distract one’s attention from the
>   present

or alternatively, and perhaps more accurately in view of the question, [fantasise](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/fantasize?q=fantasise) about what those events may be:

> Indulge in daydreaming about something desired

(Such as the consequences of getting those Powerball numbers. Many's the time I've "future reminisced" about that...)

Comment: @Alan K, daydreaming does not in any sense convey the notion of a future event. People can daydream about the past, the future, the present, or something completely imaginary. The nature of causality and the Arrow of Time are not really relevant. Any reasonable person can look forward to a future event. I look forward to the end of the work week, or to getting paid. Can I guarantee these future events will take place? Of course not. But it's both likely and reasonable to expect them to.

Comment: @barbecue: Fair comment; indeed that thought occurred to me as I was writing it and upon reflection I should have brought it up in my main answer. This was why I went on to fantasise, though. Granted one can also fantasise about past events but it is more common to fantasise about what might be.

Comment: @AlanK reminisce has an emotional connotation that the others are neglecting in their answers.  There is a difference in meaning between envision a better future and dream of a better future.  Your answer is the best, so I up voted it.  Maybe someone didn't like the light cone reference....whatever.  Asking questions about words is like asking, "I usually drive a Porsche to work but it's in the shop, today.  What's a good alternative?" and having users answer "You could ride a bicycle." (And they are not being sarcastic.)

Comment: You reminisce about the past, you daydream about the future. Done deal. Write questions like this, get two close votes, and you'll receive answers that *have* to spell this kinda stuff out - or *you're* not answering them comprehensively.

Answer (score 1):

I **prognosticate** the future myself.

Meriam-Webster:

> 1:  to foretell from signs or symptoms :  predict